# PHP function in_array does not finding a variable

Tags: php, session

I have an array of id's in `$_SESSION` called `$_SESSION['remember']`.
When I'm printing it with `print_r($_SESSION['remember'])` it shows:

```
Array ( [0] => 587064e248177eb81ed1d9f5 [1] => 587064fa48177e1a27d1d9ec )
```

Also I have variable called `$id` where I have stored id of a photo.
This `$id` variable is set to:

```
$id = "587064e248177eb81ed1d9f5";
```

so the index `0` of the array, but when I'm trying to use in_array function:

```
if (in_array($id , $_SESSION['remember'])) {
    echo "YES";
} else {
    echo " NO";
}
```

it always printing `NO`.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be awesome :) Thank You in advance.

Comment: `&id =` TYPO ?????????????

Comment: Did you include `session_start();` before accessing `$_SESSION`..?

Comment: Yes, I did include session_start(); as the first line on my php script.

Comment: var_dump() session, check string length, in case of spaces.

Comment: is this your exact code..?  Because it seems to be working for me.

Comment: This was my exact code. nogad, you're right, before and after was a space, don't know why but now it's seems to work. Thank you all a lot :)